# How do I add a comment in an Aurelia template file that will be stripped out of the compiled page?

Tags: html, comments, aurelia

I am writing an Aurelia template file and I want to add a comment to it. This is a comment that I want people who read the template file (i.e. my fellow developers) to see. However, I want it to be stripped out upon compilation - I don't want end-users of the web site to be able to inspect the page source and see the text of the comment when they visit the site. How is this done? An ordinary HTML comment (`<!--` ... `-->`) is not stripped out.

### What I have tried already

I ctrl-F'd this page: http://aurelia.io/docs/templating/basics for the word "comment". There were zero matches, so if that page provides an answer, it does so without using the word "comment".

Comment: Are you using webpack? if so, go to https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-minimizer-webpack-plugin/ and ctrl+F for 'removeComments' ;)

Comment: @c_thane, I see from your link that there is a way to make this happen using the configuration of WebPack. I have not verified that this works - I have chosen at this time to use a workaround instead of going to the trouble of doing this configuration. However if you add an answer stating your solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a project with `aurelia-cli` (in my case TS with Webpack)

You may have any template file (`.html`) containing something like

```
<template>
  <!-- this comment is for devs only -->
  <h1>${message}</h1>
</template>
```

then, to remove the comment/s once compiled (always/conditionally)

1. Open `webpack.config.js`
2. Under `module` find `rules` array
3. Find the `html-loader` section
4. Change `minimize` value to `true` or base it on build-type `production` etc

```
module.exports = ({ production }, { analyze, hmr, port, host }) => ({
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader', options: { minimize: !!production /* or just minimize: true */ } },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
});
```

`minimize` accepts the following type

```
type minimize =
  | boolean
  | {
      caseSensitive?: boolean;
      collapseWhitespace?: boolean;
      conservativeCollapse?: boolean;
      keepClosingSlash?: boolean;
      minifyCSS?: boolean;
      minifyJS?: boolean;
      removeComments?: boolean;
      removeRedundantAttributes?: boolean;
      removeScriptTypeAttributes?: boolean;
      removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes?: boolean;
    };
```

thereby enabling finer control.

To read more about it: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#minimize